# Can't copy files on external 1 tb toshiba drive

Tags: permissions, drive

I cannot copy or create folders on an external drive. It says I'm not root. Please tell me which files do I have to post here, thanks a lot!

Comment: The files on the external hard drive are not owned by you. To copy them, run the command `sudo -i nautilus` and then copy them. Then run the command `chmod +rw /path/to/coppied/files`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what filesystem is on the external drive, but if it's one that knows "owners" maybe you're not the owner of the directory/files, so can't change it. Could try going into (`cd`) the mounted drive and

`sudo chown [yourusername] -R .`

using whatever your username is (see `whoami`) so you become the owner.